# I rooted my phone and its memory got deleted. Is that normal? Any way to recover=

Tags: rooting, data-recovery, htc

I rooted my phone, a HTC, and its memory got deleted. This was the fourth telephone I rooted and I can not recall it has happened before so I was a little sloppy when I read the warnings displayed during the process (besides, it was necessary since backing up of this phone had stopped working and I needed a backup of the wifi-passwords).

Is it "normal" that the memory is intentionally deleted when rooting?

Any ways to recover? I have put the phone aside and not used it since this happened but the memory was encrypted.

Comment: Which HTC model in particular? What instructions did you follow? If you unlocked the bootloader, it is natural for the device to be wiped out on next boot as a data security precaution.

Comment: @Firelord One M9+ and the first instructions found on Google.

Comment: We don't know what instructions you "found on google". Unless we don't know the steps you've taken, we cannot answer your question. Firelord already gave you one of the clues in this context: if the process involved unlocking the bootloader, that usually involves an implicit factory reset. And no, there shouldn't be ways to recover then, that's the whole purpose of deleting the data in this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the warning you must not have read...

I imagine from my own experience with HTC and unlocking the bootloader that you followed the official process on the HTC Dev site... ( HTC Developer Website ) ... [Official page](https://www.htcdev.com/)..

Unlock bootloader page - [Unlock Bootloader..](https://www.htcdev.com/bootloader)

It will notify you prior to pressing Up to Accept the process that it will erase the Internal Memory..
 .

Recovery is not possible without specialized software for data analysis, ... I mean a Full ROM Restore...

You can restore Photos and Documents using applications like DiskDigger, as long as you have not Overwritten them.. Try not to put anything on the Data partition like new Apps or even on the Internal storage...

The internal storage is usually Emulated and is actually a folder in the Data partition...

Writing to Either Data or Internal Storage will erase the previous data....

Data usually is not Erased, but Marked as Reusable...

Deletion is a long process for the computer so it just marks the file for replacement..

Even a  " Quick Format " Does the same thing !

Comment: When I replayed the first steps of the process I found a warning at the HTC dev site (it wasn't directly hard to see but I understand why I dismissed it as another "you are on your own"-warning) but you mean there was a secondary warning on the actual phone before going forward? I shouldn't have missed that one:-(

Comment: What kind of specialized software are you referring to?

Comment: Yes in All the times I've done it using the sites official process, it makes me accept that ... It is sometimes a very short sentence in Code returned from Fastboot... Sometimes it is a massive screen with a big Red Exclamation mark Saying it... For me it is about 30% of devices that use a Big Screen to show a significant difference..  Other device's it says it on the computer in the command window... But All require pressing UP as a Signification that you Accept the Data being Erased... This is because of Data Laws.

Comment: There is no way to restore anything from encrypted partition, the encryption key is wiped. This answer is only valid for older unencrypted devices